# What is a word that means “see” (refer to), but in latin form, like “r.e.”?

Tags: word-request

What is a word that means “see” (refer to) (go see), but in latin form, like “r.e.”?
I asked this in the English stackexchange and got kicked out

Comment: It is possibly viz., but only as a stretch of its literal sense "it is permissible to see". Why is videlicit abbreviated as viz, by the way? Why not vid.?

Comment: The abbreviation "viz." goes back to Tironian shorthand, the way I heard it; that would make a fine question in its own right, though.

Comment: Qv or q.v.  (plural qq.v.) is listed in Chambers page x, but in the concise Oxford page xix they prefer cf. (short for confer) which is also in the answer given by Draconis.

Comment: _Re_ is not an initialism, but the Latin word _re_, ablative of _res_ ("thing", "matter"). Originally in the legal Latin phrase _in re X_ "in the matter of X" or "in X's legal action"

Comment: I wrote *viz.* in this sense for sometime, but stopped after finding that it rather means "that is, which means", basicly *i.e.* "id est". I shouldn't use entirely arcsne shorthand except in space constrained writing (viz. comments)

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you want to use this in an English context, so I'd suggest the abbreviation *cf*, short for *confer* "bring these things together". It's relatively common in academic contexts to mean "you should compare my results against this other work".

Another option, depending on the use case, is *qv*, short for *quod vide* or *quae vide* "which you should look at". This one's more common in reference books, used to point to a different entry in the same work rather than a different work entirely.

Comment: Note that *q.v.* has a different grammatical function than *see*: *see* takes a direct object saying what entry to go look at, whereas *q.v.* says to go look at the entry for the entity just mentioned. For example, "He was the third president of the United States (*q.v.*)" means "He was the third president of the United States (*see* Uɴɪᴛᴇᴅ Sᴛᴀᴛᴇꜱ)". So *see* is more flexible: it lets you refer to an entry whose title isn't *exactly* the preceding word or phrase.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the excellent suggestions made by Draconis, there is also the simple ***vide*** "see", abbreviated as `v.`. It is used in e.g. Lewis & Short.

https://latinlexicon.org/LNS_abbreviations.php

Comment: In my opinion, this is the correct answer for what the OP is actually asking.